# Need assistance with my python multiples finder of 3 or 5 and also 3 and 5

Tags: python

today i had a friend come home and with a program exam and one of the questions that appeared was a program to find the following multiples and show them like this, the program also requested that any number above 50 would not be accepted and error message shown,

```
1
2
multiple of 3
4
multiple of 5
7
8
multiple of 3
multiple of 5
13
14
multiple of 3 or multiple of 5
16,
```

I made a code but I cant make it show like it shows in the exam pic like the text above, this is my code so far

```
num =1
c = 0
while num != 0:
    try:
        num = int(input("Insert a number: "))
        while c < num:
            c = c + 1
            print(c)
            if num == 0:
                exit()
            if c % 3:
                print("multiple of  3")
            if c % 5:
                print("multiple of  5")
            if c % 5 or 3:
                print("multiple of 3 or and 5")
            if c >= 50:
                print("Error")
    except ValueError:
            print("Please insert a number")
```

i tried that code that I made with my limited experience 2 days peak learning python but with Garry's mod e2 coding experience, it's small what I learned there but I watched and read some tutorials online but can't seem to make that work like said above, can somebody enlighten me on what i might have done wrong, i want to learn more of programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not x % y` and check for 3 and 5 first.

```
num =1
c = 0
while num != 0:
    try:
        num = int(input("Insert a number: "))
        while c < num:
            c = c + 1
            if num == 0:
                exit()
            if c >= 50:
                print("Error")
            elif not c % 5 and not c % 3:
                print("multiple of 3 or and 5")
            elif not c % 3:
                print("multiple of  3")
            elif not c % 5:
                print("multiple of  5")
            else:
                print(c)
    except ValueError:
            print("Please insert a number")
```

Output

```
Insert a number: 16
1
2
multiple of  3
4
multiple of  5
multiple of  3
7
8
multiple of  3
multiple of  5
11
multiple of  3
13
14
multiple of 3 or and 5
16
```

Comment: This is correct, but imo `c % 5 == 0` reads more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you need 2 while loops to do this.

```
while True:
    num = input(":")
    try:
        num = int(num)
        if num <= 0:print("Too small, try again.")
        elif num > 50:print("Too big, try again.")
        else:
            print("Multiple of 3 or 5") if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0 else print("Multiple of 3") if num % 3 == 0 else print("Multiple of 5") if num % 5 == 0 else ""
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a valid number!")
```

In my code, I check if the number is smaller than 0 or bigger than 50, and then I check for mod of 3 and 5, 5, 3.
And sorry for the complex code, I have a habit of trying to keep my code in 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Step through each line one at a time and think about how you will arrive at a "true" condition for each if statement you've written. In your example, if the user puts a number higher than 49, you will print "error" on each line until the loop ends when c finally becomes equal to num.

First, you need to see if you're going to run the loop, so make sure you don't if the user inputs anything but a number between 1 and 50 inclusive.

Once you're in the loop, you must determine what will be printed for each iteration: one of 3 messages about the number or the number itself. So, you must determine which of the four options you'll be printing, then print that output.

```
try:
    num = int(input('Insert a number: '))
    if num > 50 or num < 1:
        raise
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            msg = 'multiple of 3 or multiple of 5'
        elif i % 3 == 0:
            msg = 'multiple of 3'
        elif i % 5 == 0:
            msg = 'multiple of 5'
        else:
            msg = f'{i}'
        print(msg)
except:
    print('ERROR: Invalid Entry')
```

Output:

```
Insert a number: 16
1
2
multiple of 3
4
multiple of 5
multiple of 3
7
8
multiple of 3
multiple of 5
11
multiple of 3
13
14
multiple of 3 or multiple of 5
16
```